# While loop returns errors over and over after the first error

Tags: java, validation, while-loop

In a while loop I made the loop wont return a valid answer after one invalid input and repeats "Error! Invalid customer type. Try again." over and over until I close the program. If I enter R or C as the input the first time it works fine. When I enter anything else and I get the error message "Error! Invalid customer type. Try again." like I should be which is intentional. However after that error entering r or c gives me the error again and any input I make returns the error message over and over until I close the program.  Can someone please tell me whats wrong in my code that causing this?

```
public static String getValidCustomerType(Scanner sc)
{
    String customerType = ("");
      System.out.println("Enter the Customer Type");
      customerType = sc.next() ;
      boolean isValid = false;
      while (isValid == false)
      {
       if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R")|customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C") ) 
       {
         isValid = true;
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.println("Error! Invalid customer type. Try again ");
       }   
       sc.nextLine() ;
      }
   return customerType ;
}
```

Comment: you need to assign customerType each time in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not assign to `customerType` inside the while loop. better yet move it to the start.

```
public static String getValidCustomerType(Scanner sc)
{
    String customerType = ("");

      boolean isValid = false;
      while (isValid == false)
      {
          System.out.println("Enter the Customer Type");
          customerType = sc.nextLine() ;
       if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R")|customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C") ) 
       {
         isValid = true;
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.println("Error! Invalid customer type. Try again ");
       }   
      }
   return customerType ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to move the input call inside of the while loop. Otherwise the customerType variable is always the same.

```
public static String getValidCustomerType(Scanner sc)
{
    String customerType = ("");
      System.out.println("Enter the Customer Type");
      // move this to while loop
      //customerType = sc.next() ;
      boolean isValid = false;
      while (isValid == false)
      {
       // get input here
       customerType = sc.next() ;
       if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R")|customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C") ) 
       {
         isValid = true;
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.println("Error! Invalid customer type. Try again ");
       }   
       sc.nextLine() ;
      }
   return customerType ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: `|`(bitwise OR) is not the same as `||` which is a boolean OR operator. And secondly you're not assigning `customerType` again - the fix is below.

```
while (isValid == false)
  {
   if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R")||customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C") ) 
   {
     isValid = true;
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println("Error! Invalid customer type. Try again ");
   }   
    customerType = sc.nextLine() ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the do while loop with a sentinel. This guarantees that the code is executed at least [once](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

```
    public static String getValidCustomerType(Scanner sc) {
        String customerType;
        boolean isValid = false;

        System.out.println("Enter the Customer Type");

        do {
            customerType = sc.next();

            if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R")|customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C") )  {
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid customer type. Try again ");
            }   
        } while(!isValid);

        return customerType ;
    }
```